# Does brushing hamper my fasting?

Tags: hadith, sawm

Will tasting toothpaste while brushing teeth break my fast?

Answer (score 3):

well, on the other case. some of my country's ulama said that brushing teeth is makruh so they often tell to not doing that around fasting. but someother says it's welcome for us to do that as long as the water or the paste is not swallowed into our body.

Answer (score 3):

Brush your teeth while you fast during Ramadan, but be careful that you don't swallow anything. You can use any fluoride toothpaste, but make sure you don't gulp it down.

Answer (score 2):

Brushing the teeth during the fast will not break the fast until you swallow it. So be careful during brushing, don't swallow the toothpaste and water when you brush your teeth. But it can be broken when you brush your teeth due to hard toothbrush,it hurts the gums the blood come out from the gums and if that blood  mixed with saliva and you swallow it then it will break the fast.

Answer (score 2):

Brushing your teeth during fasting is not hampered your fast until or unless you swallowed the toothpaste. You can use any toothpaste but be careful don't gulped it down. Dental hygiene paid heed to as one following the strict sovereignty during the month of blessings holy Ramadan

Answer (score 2):

no brushing teeth doesn't breaks fast until and unless you swallowed the paste.